# PhpStorm keymap for Sublime Text 3

Tags: phpstorm, sublimetext3, shortcut, keymaps

I want to have PhpStorm keyboard shortcuts inside Sublime Text 3. Is it possible? How can I do it? I use Linux Mint if there is any difference.

I use these shortcuts the most:

- reformat code
- comment
- PHPDoc comments
- duplicate line/selected word/selected sentence ... (with one single shortcut `Ctrl+D`),
- select word/line/childs (`Ctrl+W`),

I like the last one a lot -- you can select whatever is inside a tag or braces or other things with `Ctrl+W` and if you press it more than once the current parents whole childs and then current parent and then current parents parent and so on will be selected.

I want actually all of PhpStorm's shortcuts inside SublimeText 3.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no possibility to export keys from phpstorm into sublime, but you can specify your keys in sublime with same values like in phpstorm, for example:

[image]
[image]

After that, you can export: `settings.jar` from phpstorm and save `Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` from sublime somewhere on drive or cloud so you will have this keys forever. You can loosely import this keys in different versions of phpstorm and copy-paste keys from sublime-keymap into different versions of sublime.